# retrieve subcollections in cloud firestore

Tags: typescript, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

Let's have a biz model defined like this

```
export inteface Item {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

export interface Container {
    id: string;
    items: Item[];
}
```

In Cloud Firestore we have collection `/containers`
and each container contains collection `/items` with documents.
Each document has field `name`.
So the structure inside Cloud Firestore copies our biz model.

Now I'd like to retrieve specific container with its collection of items.

```
getContainer(idIn: string) {
  const document: AngularFirestoreDocument<Container> = this.afs.doc('containers/' + idIn);
  const document$: Observable<Container> = document.snapshotChanges().map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.data() as Container;
      const id = a.payload.id;
      return this.getItems(idIn).map( item => {
        return {id, ...data, items: item};
      });
    });
  return document$;
}

getItems(id: string) {
  const collection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Item> = this.afs.collection('containers/' + id + '/items');

  return collection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Item;
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;
      return {id, ...data};
    });
  });
}
```

But i keep getting this error about missing id on returning Observable.
Compiling with typescript 2.6.2.

```
error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Observable<{ items: { 'id': string;  'item': string; }[]; 'id': string...' is not assignable to type  'Observable<Container>'.
 Type 'Observable<{ items: { 'id': string; 'item': string; }[]; 'id': string...' is not assignable to type 'Container'.
 Property ''id'' is missing in type 'Observable<{ items: { 'id': string; 'item': string; }[]; 'id': string...'.
```

Could anyone point out what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me your return data is not same as the Interface modal. You only specified `id` and `items` fields in the interface, so it will be

```
  const data = a.payload.data() as Container;
  const id = a.payload.id;
  let items=[];
  this.getItems(idIn).valueChanges().subscribe(res=>{
      res.forEach(item=>{
        items.push(item);
      })
    });
  return {id:id, items: items};
```

Comment: At first glance i don't think this is also correct. But i was wondering, if reference `data` from mehtod `getContainer()` could overshadow the the reference with the same name `data` in the method `getItems()`. I am new to the javascript/typescript. Could it be scope issue?(i can't confirm it now)

Comment: try to change the name `const data` in `getItems()` and confirm.

Comment: i am not sure about the scope if you written inside another function

Comment: I would prezoom that calling method in typescript would also create the stack frame and move stack pointer but like i said i don't know typescript well. So it's possible it's all in 1 scope and 1st `data` is overshadowed.

Comment: One more thing i noticed you need to pass array of items.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading nested collections in Firestore to populate in my case an Expansion widget. See my solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51057195/5013735

The trick is in to create a structure like:

```
  List<Widget> _getChildren() {
    List<Widget> children = [];
    documents.forEach((doc) {
      children.add(
        ProjectsExpansionTile(
          name: doc['name'],
          projectKey: doc.documentID,
          firestore: firestore,
        ),
      );
    });
    return children;
  }
```