# how can i show an ExpandedTile beneath a Listtile when trailing icon is pressed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to show details on the same screen beneath the List Tile. I have implemented ListTile but i need to show the details in expansionTile when trialing icon of listTile is pressed.

ListTile Is:
[image]

I used Expanded Tile but this design cannot be followed.
Expanded Tile is:
[image]

Comment: did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45456173/4366237)?

Comment: I will look into it, @UmairM thanx