# How to insert date data in database laragon using flutter?

Tags: laravel, datetime, flutter, laragon

I dont know how to insert date data in database laragon in flutter app. I have done  the GUI for the insert date using package "flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.1.5" but I dont know how to forward date data selected to database.

I have dont the select date as shown in code .dart below.
I'm not sure how to connect it to api from database.

**insertdate.dart**

```
RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                elevation: 4.0,
                onPressed: () {
                  DatePicker.showDatePicker(context,
                      theme: DatePickerTheme(
                        containerHeight: 210.0,
                      ),
                      showTitleActions: true,
                      minTime: DateTime(2019, 1, 1),
                      maxTime: DateTime(2030, 12, 31), onConfirm: (date) {
                    print('confirm $date');
                    departDate = '${date.year} - ${date.month} - ${date.day}';
                    setState(() {});
                  }, currentTime: DateTime.now(), locale: LocaleType.en);
                },
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  height: 50.0,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.date_range,
                                  size: 25.0,
                                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                                ),
                               new Text(
                                  // controller: dateDepartController,
                                  " $departDate",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 18.0),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "  Change",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 18.0),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
              ),
```

Below is the API for post data date in laravel. All data can be updated when I test run API in the Postman. I just cant figured out how to post data in the flutter.

**api**

```
     public function PostTrip(Request $request)
         {
            $id = $request->id;
            $fr_country = $request->fr_country;
            $ar_country = $request->ar_country;
            $traveller_id = $request->taveller_id;
            $departDate = $request->departDate;
            $returnDate = $request->returnDate;

            $getId = User::where('id',$id)->first()->id;
            //// called country based on id ////
            $getFCountry = Countries::where('id',$fr_country)->first()->country;
            $getACountry = Countries::where('id',$ar_country)->first()->country;


             $user = PosTrip::create([
                'fr_country' =>$getFCountry,     
                'ar_country' =>$getACountry,           
                'traveller_id'=>$getId,
                'departDate'=>$departDate,
                'returnDate'=>$returnDate,

            ]);


                $datamsg = response()->json([
                'success' => array("text"=>"Done!")
                ]);
                return $datamsg->content();



         }
```

I want the date update in table in database.

Comment: First of all, laragon is a webserver, not API. So the question is invalid. Since you are using laragon, i'm guessing you are familiar with laravel. If you are, you can develop API in laravel. If you want to know how to post data to api, you can follow this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645260/how-to-implement-api-calls-in-flutter

Comment: You can learn more about laravel api in https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources and https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing

Comment: I have update the question.Its a function API that I have tried.